# Cursor returns to center when using external screen and closing laptop lid

Tags: windows-10, display, tv, cursor, lid

I have been attaching my laptop to my TV for streaming (of things I can't get on my TV). I set the laptop such that I can close the lid and not put it to sleep.

The problem is, when I close the lid on my laptop, the cursor lights up right in the center of the screen. This is no good for watching streaming video. Is there a way that I can make the cursor remain where it was when I closed the lid (which is always off of the screen)?

I realize I can use an external mouse to move the cursor out of the way, but this seems like a step I shouldn't have to do!

(I am using an Acer Aspire 3 laptop with Windows 10.)

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way around the simple fact that by closing the lid you shutdown the internal monitor and whenever using two or more monitors and on turn off the pointer pops up in the other one. You may try disabling the internal one before closing the lid though.

Comment: ChanganAuto: I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows 10 on which I can close the lid, the internal monitor goes off, but the image on the TV remains constant. There has to be a reason/setting that is different between the two.